# Javascript GetElementById .href issue

Tags: javascript

Im amending the href of a button but for some reason it doesnt seem to take. I do the same thing on a number of buttons however this is the only one with an issue.

Heres the code as it stands.

```
var shortnum = callid.substring(0,7);
var uglysrc = "list_num.php?caller=" + shortnum;
document.getElementById('uglymugs').href = uglysrc;
window.alert(document.getElementById('uglymugs').href); 
document.getElementById('uglymugs').style.background='#FF0000';
```

I added in the alert to check what was happening and it correctly shows the ref I want however on hovering the button it still shows the original href and clicking it takes you to the original? The background color of the button changes to red as expected therefore there's no error created prior to the last line.

Its had me stumped for 2 hours, its exactly the same method as I use for the other buttons and all others wok as expected ie the button href changes then the hover changes and it takes you where you expect to go.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for your usecase

Comment: Providing your `window.alert` works, your code seems fine. Is the site online? Can we see it? If not, please provide more code which can cause this issus, something's not right, and it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: could you try .setAttribute("href", uglysrc) instead of .href = uglysrc???

Comment: Can you put it on JSFiddle ?

Comment: Does something else trigger when the link is clicked, like an `onclick` event?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  It's something else that hasn't been provided.  Please make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using JSFiddle.

Comment: Show the corresponding HTML please.

Comment: Ice not used jsfiddle before, Ive added the function to it but arent sure how much more stuff Id need to add. Id assume Id probably need virtually the whole page to get it to run. https://jsfiddle.net/sr1xdzLk/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use: 
`window.alert(document.getElementById('uglymugs').getAttribute('href'));`

If you know that uglymugs is already pointing to your href (anchor link) of interest.

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, Ive found the issue and it was outside the code. I've recently taken over this app and wouldnt have done it this way myself so thats whats lost me.

The code for the button was:

```
<a id ="uglybutton" href="list_num.php" target="frame"><button id="uglymugs">UglyMugs</button></a>
```

Setting the href of the button was never going to do anything as its the  link that needed setting.

Apologies, for wasting everyones time but it took looking at things differently to sort it. Many thanks to all that replied.